# Hibernate how to commit transaction even when exception pops up

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

i have a method in Service A

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    anotherService.doThing();
  }
}
```

And another method in Service B

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
public void doThing() {
  ...
  try {
    repository.insertRandomValue();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }      
  ...
}
```

My problem is that when "repository.insertRandomValue()" throws ConstraintViolationException for example, then even tho it was caught in catch(), the thread ends with

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

I have tried setting the propagation to REQUIRES_NEW and tried to set up transaction manager and GlobalRollbackOnParticipationFailure to false.

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
  JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  manager.setGlobalRollbackOnParticipationFailure(false);
  return manager;
}
```

I want it to simply ignore the failed insert attampts and continue working. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate documentation is very clear that you have to rollback (section 5.16 Exception Handling):

> If the JPA EntityManager or the Hibernate-specific Session throws an
> exception, including any JDBC SQLException, you have to immediately
> rollback the database transaction and close the current EntityManager
> or Session.
>
> Certain methods of the JPA EntityManager or the Hibernate Session will
> not leave the Persistence Context in a consistent state. As a rule of
> thumb, no exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable.
> Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling the close() method
> in a finally block.
>
> Rolling back the database transaction does not put your business
> objects back into the state they were at the start of the transaction.
> This means that the database state and the business objects will be
> out of sync. Usually, this is not a problem because exceptions are not
> recoverable and you will have to start over after rollback anyway.

So you need to check beforehand if there would be a ConstraintViolationException