# Transaction marked as RollbackOnly - no @Transactional

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm working with a framework that uses EntityManager's transactions to give a transaction context to batch treatments. (not @Transactional)

For each item treated, I use a SQL native query (JPA - ORACLE) that contains a UNION ALL to process a transitive closure on a certain relation.

Something like this :

```
  public String getMostRecent(String var) {
                String sql = """"
                    WITH testo(a,b) AS
                    (SELECT a,b
                        FROM   foo
                        WHERE  a = :var
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT t2.a,
                               t2.b
                        FROM   foo t2,
                                 testo
                        WHERE  t2.a = testo.b)
                        SELECT a FROM testo WHERE  b IS NULL;
    """;

           
                Query q = broker.getContext().createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter("var", var);
                try {
                    List<Object> result = q.getResultList();
                   
                   // if var is not part of the transitive closure, it's already the most recent record
                    if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
                       return var;
                    } else {
                        return result.get(0).toString();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // we couldn't find the most recent record corresponding to var because of a cyclic reference. 
                    // we thus  return the one given as parameter" + var+ ".);
                    return var;
                    
                } 

            }
```

When the said relation present a cycle I get the following exception :

```
2022-03-16 16:28:17,645 WARN  o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 32044, SQLState: 99999
2022-03-16 16:28:17,650 ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query
2022-03-16 16:28:17,650 ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query
```

This exception is caught in the try catch, but that doesn't matter to us. If the query fails, "var" is a "good enough" return value.
The problem however is that this exception seem to marks the transaction as rollback only ... which thus rollback the treatment of all the items in the transaction...

I found a way to get over the problem by using a nested transaction just to execute this SQL statement  as follows:

```
 public String getMostRecent(String var) {
                String sql = """"
                    WITH testo(a,b) AS
                    (SELECT a,b
                        FROM   foo
                        WHERE  a = :var
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT t2.a,
                               t2.b
                        FROM   foo t2,
                                 testo
                        WHERE  t2.a = testo.b)
                        SELECT a FROM testo WHERE  b IS NULL;
    """;


                Query q = broker.getContext().createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter("var", var);
                try {
                    getTransactionManager().beginTransaction(TransactionMode.REQUIRES_NEW);
                    List<Object> result = q.getResultList();

                   // if var is not part of the transitive closure, it's already the most recent record
                    if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
                       return var;
                    } else {
                        return result.get(0).toString();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // we couldn't find the most recent record corresponding to var because of a cyclic reference. 
                    // we thus  return the one given as parameter" + var+ ".);
                    return var;

                } finally {
                    getTransactionManager().endTransaction(false);
                }

            }
```

( it works for me as I do not care if the nested transaction rollbacks from the moment that the main transaction gets committed).
But I don't find the solution sexy.

Also, I'm wondering in somewhere else in our project, we have rollback that happens without us noticing because of this phenomenon (project is pretty old ...)

Is there a way to prevent the automatic marking of transactions to Rollback only in case of a cached ORA error ?

Is there a way to specify something similar to the "noRollbackFor" of the @Transactional attribute ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887675/continue-with-transaction-after-exception-jpa does this help?

Comment: no, the framework I'm working with doesn't use @Transactional

Comment: Well, this probably needs to be worked into your txn mgmt code.

Comment: My hands are tied concerning the framework I'm using. I'm just building on top of it.
The transaction management that comes with it relies on hibernate Entity Manager transactions directly. Isn't there really nothing we can do ?

Comment: I don't think you can change transactional behaviours on an inflight transaction.  IMO, nesting is your best bet.

Comment: ok for not being able to change the transactional behaviours on an inflight transaction, but isn't there a way, before the transaction start to configure it so that the exception doesn't trigger the rollback Only ? I did a few tests and I noticed that only the ORA exception marked the transaction as rollback only. Other exceptions like self thrown or division by zero didn't have any impact on the transaction

Comment: Again, it depends on the txn mgmt code.  You're using hibernate?  Can you add the txn mgmt code from your application?

Comment: we use hibernate and jpa. When I looked deeper into the code of the framework, it seems that in my case the transaction relies on javax.persistence.EntityTransaction from javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar

Hard to follow as there's a lot of wrapper/polymorphism

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662799/hibernate-how-to-commit-transaction-even-when-exception-pops-up looks like it's not possible.

Comment: I see, I'll keep my dirty workaround then. Thank you for having tried ^^